# Using USB JTAG probe with ARM & MIPS

Tags: debuggers, hardware, arm, mips, jtag

Can someone advice USB JTAG probe designed for both ARM and MIPS target boards, and which works with the OpenOCD and UrJTAG? I know Flyswatter2..

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the [Bus Blaster](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Blaster)? It is an FT2232 based board which has both ARM and MIPS eJTAG support. The Bus Pirate (also sold by Dangerous Prototypes) also has the ability to perform JTAG, but it runs much slower (like, 10 bits a minute or something ridiculous).

Comment: Bus Blaster v3 look interesting, will definitely consider it. Small drawback is it have no protective enclosure, so it should be done by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following devices successfully with OpenOCD:

- https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/JTAG/ARM-USB-OCD/ (only ARM)
- http://amontec.axianet.ch/jtagkey/jtagkey (multi-architecture)

The Bus Blaster is compatible with OpenOCD as it was a jtagkey and therefore I think  it will satisfy your needs accordingly.